# Multiple boxplots in R created sequentially (preferably with base)

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

My data is (sort of) like this:

```
    thing  value
    a      100
    a      101
    .      .
    a      99
    b      201
    b      202
    .      .
    b      199
```

I want to compare the median of the values by thing. Normally I would make a boxplot with something like boxplot(value ~ thing, data = table), but there is a catch.

**The problem**

The number of values of each thing is about 100,000. Consequently I have had to process my table in sections. I process all values for thing a, then all values for thing b, etc.

Is there a way to make a boxplot and then add more plots to it, like using plot and dots? I want to use the base plotting system if possible (to make the plots consistent).

However, if that isn't possible, I guess ggplot2 might have to be the go.

I should add, what I'm hoping to achieve is something like the image here:
http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/images/boxplot1.jpg

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you need to process your data in sections. 100000 values per group is not a problem _per se_ for boxplot. Thus, I don't understand your "Consequently".

Comment: you can add boxplots to a boxplot with parameter `add=T` and the "right" `xlim` : 1st boxplot `boxplot(value1,data=thing1,at=1.1,xlim=c(1,2))`, 2nd boxplot `boxplot(value2,data=thing2,at=1.9,add=T)`

Comment: That's looking like what I'm after CathG, I'll try it. I did find the add=T, but it just added over the top. I was missing the at parameter. Feel free to make your comment an answer!

Comment: Thanks Henrik. The 100,000 rows isn't an issue for boxplot, but for the table and the. Also keep in mind it is about 100,000 per thing. I have a hundred or so things (not just a and b). I'm only comparing about 10 at a time, but even that gives a table with 1,000,000 rows. Possible, but getting nasty, I use data.table and try to keep to about 100,000 or less.